# Create app logout event

Tags: android, logout, navigation-drawer

I'm using navigation drawer to display all the items like `Setting, Profile, Contact Us, About Us, Logout` when clicked on any of these items then it should display in a fragment or another activity.

I tried to creating `Logout Fragment` but it didn't work using Activity & Intent.

How can I get when logout is clicked, it should logout from the app completely like it happens with any banking app.

Comment: share you logout code , not clear

Comment: @jainishkapadia Please don't add "regards, thanks" to questions

Comment: Put your code..

Comment: What makes you think you need a whole Fragment / Activity to just logout?

Comment: Not able to post the code...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create fragment for logout, on click of logout just run below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: shall i add this in NavigationDrawer?                                                                                       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        android.app.Fragment fragment=null;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id== R.id.nav_logout){     .................Here............}

Answer (score 0):

I have created dialog as follow:

```
    public void logoutDialog() {
        /**
         * Create Alert DialogBuilder */
        final AlertDialog.Builder logoutAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final RowLogoutDialogsBinding logoutDialogsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), R.layout.row_logout_dialogs, null, false);
        View logoutView = logoutDialogsBinding.getRoot();
        logoutAlert.setView(logoutView);

        /*
         * Create Alert Dialogs */
        final AlertDialog mLogoutDialog = logoutAlert.create();
        mLogoutDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.logout_dialog_title));
        mLogoutDialog.show();

        /*
         * Layout for dialog */
        setFontFace(logoutDialogsBinding.logoutMessage);
        logoutDialogsBinding.logoutNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLogoutDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        logoutDialogsBinding.logoutYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLogoutDialog.dismiss();
                AccountAuthenticator.removeAccount(mContext);
                finish();

                // DO OTHER PROCESS OF LOGOUT like clear PREFERENCE, DB

                Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.string_loggedout_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

by clicking on that menu item, I just opened that dialog.

```
case R.id.nav_logout:
    logoutDialogs();
    break;
```

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer will be helpful in future,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //CLEARS INSTANCES OF ALL YOUR ACTIVITIES
        startActivity(intent);
        finish(); //CLEARS BACKSTACK ACTIVITIES
```